# How can I limit user actions based on their proximity to a fixed point in iOS?

Tags: xcode, ios, geolocation, foursquare

I guess what I am trying to do should be simple, but don’t know how to search for it!

What I wanna do is: the user will vote for a music, but the user can only vote if he is 2km away from a fixed location (lat,lon).

Can you suggest some links that can help me implement this?!

Cheers.

Comment: 2kl? 2 kilo-liters? That's a lot of boozing just to be able to vote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this...

```
@interface YourLocationViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> 
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

...

```
/**
 * Start tracking updates for location. 
 * Call this from viewLoad or something.
 */
-(void) trackUpdates {

    self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    /* Pinpoint our location with the following accuracy:
     *
     *     kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation  highest + sensor data
     *     kCLLocationAccuracyBest               highest     
     *     kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters   10 meters   
     *     kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters      100 meters
     *     kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer          1000 meters 
     *     kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers    3000 meters
     */
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;

    /* Notify changes when device has moved x meters.
     * Default value is kCLDistanceFilterNone: all movements are reported.
     */
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f;

    // update location
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    CLLocationDistance meters = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:fixedPoint];
    if (meters>2000){
        // drink a shot
    }
}
```

Comment: cool solution! just implemented right now, but I dont know why the core location is not getting started?! some trick is missing?!

Comment: ok, here is it: http://pastebin.com/kmwcdJu5 , it`s not even getting the "locationManager" log point!

Comment: Note that you are creating the locationManager with autorelease so the instance is lost as soon as you exit the method. Maybe you should add it as a class variable.